# Python: pandas groupby ID, add values of multiple columns until a break condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': ['1','1','1','2','2','3','4'],
'transfer_time': [0,10,12,0,19,0,0],
'trip_time': [20,30,9,10,15,12,16],
'is_final_stop': [0,1,0,0,1,1,1]
})
print(df)
```

which looks like below:

```
id  is_final_stop   transfer_time   trip_time
1   0                 0               20
1   1                 10              30
1   0                 12              9
2   0                 0               10
2   1                 19              15
3   1                 0               12
4   1                 0               16
```

I need to calculate journey_time = transfer_time+trip_time, grouped by id, until the is_final_stop flag = 1. (The ids after this instance shouldn't be considered to add to the journey_time)

The solution should look like below:

```
id journey_time
1  60
2  44
3  12
4  16
```

Would appreciate a solution which can work efficiently on a data frame with 4 million rows. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate an "inclusion" flag via a *reverse* `cumsum`, then use `GroupBy` + `sum` on aggregate time:

```
inc_flag = df.iloc[::-1].groupby('id')['is_final_stop'].cumsum().iloc[::-1].astype(bool)

res = df[inc_flag].groupby('id')[['transfer_time', 'trip_time']].sum().sum(1)\
                  .rename('total_time').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  id  total_time
0  1          60
1  2          44
2  3          12
3  4          16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in a groupby-apply and a custom function:

```
def func(g):
    return g[g['is_final_stop'].cumsum().cumsum() < 2][['trip_time', 'transfer_time']].sum().sum()

df2 = df.groupby('id').apply(func).rename('total_time').reset_index()
#   id  total_time
# 0  1          60
# 1  2          44
# 2  3          12
# 3  4          16
```